# Installation SwashBuckle does not add swaggerconfig.cs in c# framework

Tags: c#, .net, swashbuckle

Fresh new application, using .net framework 4.7.2. Web api 2 MVC.

I simply wish to add Swagger to it. Every tutorial i read says "Install the swashbuckle nuget package and go to swaggerconfig.cs". Yet, when i install the package, i dont have a swaggerconfig.cs.

I've strolled the internet for a better part of the day now and i've patched up a swaggerconfig from their git repo and some registeration stuff, but im now stuck on the fact that no swagger.json is being generated.

So i feel like im doing manual labor where some automatic install procedure is failing. But i can't figure out... what.

I'd be grateful for any help, i can't really find anything related to this topic

Installed both swashbuckle and swashbuckle.net45 in any combination. But it doesn't generate the file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've also experienced issues with SwashBuckle. Both [SwashBuckle](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle) and [SwashBuckle.net45](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Swashbuckle.Net45/) don't seem to be actively maintained (last updates are over 2 years ago).

I recommend you check out [Swagger.net](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Swagger-Net/) which is still actively maintained. It also comes with a more modern UI then swashbuckle does.I don't recall having the issues I had with SwashBuckle, using Swagger.net.

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Swagger-Net/

Comment: Thanks! I've overlooked the fact it is not being maintained xD thanks for the tip on Swagger.net, works like a charm